# Why is ProcessWorkItems being called multiple times with the same items?

Tags: development

I've written a timer job inheriting from [SPWorkItemJobDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spworkitemjobdefinition.aspx). For some reason I'm seeing the [ProcessWorkItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms428675.aspx) method called multiple times for the same work items (i.e. they have the same batch ID). It's like they are never cleared up and removed from the queue.

The timer job uses [SPJobLockType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spjoblocktype.aspx).None. I've tried SPJobLockType.Job as well without any change to this behaviour.

Here's how the work item is added to the queue, from an application page:

```
SPContext.Current.Site.AddWorkItem(
    Guid.NewGuid(),
    DateTime.UtcNow,
    Constants.LinkCheckWorkItemType,
    SPContext.Current.Web.ID,
    SPContext.Current.Site.ID,
    1, //itemId,
    false,
    Guid.Empty, // itemGuid
    Guid.NewGuid(), // batch ID
    SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID,
    null,
    listId,
    Guid.Empty);
```

Here's the ProcessWorkItems method in the timer job:

```
public override void ProcessWorkItems(SPContentDatabase db, SPWorkItemCollection workItems)
{
    foreach (SPWorkItem workItem in workItems)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(workItem.ParentId))
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(workItem.WebId))
        {
            var processor = new LinkCheckProcessor(site, web, workItem.UserId);
            processor.ProcessLinks();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this is occurring?

Comment: how many timer services in the farm? 1? 2007?

Comment: @djeeg: 1 server. Dev in 2010, test in 2010 and 2007 (shortly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should manually delete processed woritems.

Comment: [SPWorkItemCollection.DeleteWorkItem()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spworkitemcollection.deleteworkitem.aspx) - aaagh! I thought I looked everywhere for this!

Comment: WorkItems provides reliable queue. If your code crashes workitem should not disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Should you be overriding `ProcessWorkItem` instead, that seems to be the extension point?

```
protected virtual bool ProcessWorkItem(SPContentDatabase contentDatabase, SPWorkItemCollection workItems, SPWorkItem workItem, SPJobState jobState)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

`ProcessWorkItems` seems to have a lot of utility functionality (ProgressUpdate, Tracing)

Comment: According [to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439190.aspx), ProcessWorkItems is the one to override and there's example community content showing this too. Also ProcessWorkItem isn't available to override in SP 2007 which I'm also targeting. Nice find though!

Comment: ah yes, ProcessWorkItem looks to be 2010 only

Comment: the Execute method in reflector does not seem to reference `SPJobLockType.Job`, which means the only other locking type is `SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase`, have you tried that?

Comment: I have UI to schedule the timer job and have found that 2007 only allows me to do that using `SPJobLockType.None`. (If you want to see an unusual use of if/while check out `Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWorkItemJobDefinition.Update()` in 2007!) This part of the API seems pretty flaky and changed a lot in 2010. Maybe I'll have to live with it.